# Does the iPhone's passcode protect the SIM?

Tags: security, find-my-iphone, sim

So my iPhone was just stolen. I have a long - 8 digit - pin. I'm also on the beta version of iOS 7. I think I have Find my iPhone installed and enabled.

It's apparently "offline" - it's standard practice to turn a phone off straight after stealing it, according to the police. I gave the police my Apple logon details, and I'm hoping the crims are dumb enough to turn it back on at some point.

I don't know whether I need to or should cancel my SIM. I'm sure they won't be able to get in to the phone for a while, at least until iOS 7 is publicly cracked. My concern is them taking out the SIM and racking up a phone bill. I'm on Tesco Mobile so the contract is cheap, but overages and non-UK-geographic calls are a bitch.

Is my SIM in any way protected?

Answer (score 2):

**If you did not use a dedicated SIM-Pin then your SIM is not protected.**

In other words, if you lose your iPhone someone can easily take the SIM card out of the iPhone and use it it in a different phone.

The iPhone PIN only protects the contents of the iPhone NOT the SIM card.
You have to use a SIM pin to protect the SIM card, it's available in the iPhone settings.

**So if you lost an unlocked/unprotected SIM card, you should immediately call your provider and cancel the SIM card. They can send you a new one.**

Comment: I would start your correct answer by a **Not at all!** `[return]`.